# Post request error in expess.js TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;fullName&#39; of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Hi all I am new express and try to post data from postman to data the error  `TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;fullName&#39; of undefined`
So does anybody know how to fix it ? thank you

[image]
[image]

[image: enter image description here][1]] https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzVKq.png

Comment: install the body-parser module and insert the below code in server.js

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: @mirwaleed after I fallow you I got the error like (node:3744) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `cl_users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms  so it mean the backend already got the request from frontend right ?

Comment: use async await sigunp method

Answer (score 0):

In route.js remove line 2 (require('request')) unused import, sometimes it will cause problem.

If it is not working install body-parser for parsing in server.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// for json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Refer [This site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) for read more about body parser

Comment: var express =  require('express')
var app = express()
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var dotenv = require('dotenv')
var routeUrls = require('./route/route')
var cors = require('cors')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
dotenv.config()
 
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS, () => console.log("Database connected"))
app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());   But it stall error

Comment: did you installed body-parser ?

Comment: Yes I'm already installed the body-parser and insert it to server.js